# Numpy: access specific ndarray item using cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

How do I access a specific location in a numpy array of runtime-determined shape using cython?

```
shape = (2,3,4)
x = np.zeros(shape=shape)
x[(0, 1, 2)]  # standard
x[[0], [1], [2]]  # standard

cdef np.ndarray loc = np.zeros(len(shape), dtype=np.int)
x[loc]  # doesn't work since x[[1,2,3]]
x[tuple(loc)]  # works but I assume is not as fast as can be made
```

As a corollary, the shape stays consistent across the entire operation of the program, determined through settings+reading file in. Is it possible/better to move calculating the shape to before program execution and use this calculation to take advantage of ndim in functions accepting the array x? I have little experience with static types.

Comment: In Python you could construct this tuple with `(0,)*len(shape)`; even in cython that's probably faster than working with the same size `ndarray`.  `numpy` code also constructs indexing tuples with tuple concatenation.

Comment: The above was just an example, I build/calculate loc at runtime so I can't just create a 0'd tuple.

Comment: If this is something you do repeatedly in a loop you might get better speed with a `c` style indexing.  I'd study the cython memoryview documentation.  There's also a nice numpy tutorial on iteration that ends with a cython example using `nditer`.

Comment: This seems to be what I want, thanks very much for the `nditer` tip.